# Xcode 5 autolayout issue

Tags: xcode, view, simulator, viewcontroller, xcode5

I added a ViewController and selected metrics as Inferred for all.
Also tried doing both Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Add Missing Constraints / Reset to Suggested Constraints.

View that is attached to ViewController's mode is Scale To Fill and all Autosize related boxes are ticked.

I am using the below code:

```
if (splashView.frame.size.height == 568.00) {//for iphone5
    [pngPic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone5_splash.png"]];
    screenTrackLoc = CGPointMake(splashView.frame.size.width - 45, 60);
}
else {//iphone 4
    [pngPic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone4_splash.png"]];
    screenTrackLoc = CGPointMake(splashView.frame.size.width - 45, 40);
}
```

And for 3.5 inch simulator I am still getting 568.00 result for height. What am I missing?